# How to load highcharts annotations module in react typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, highcharts

I am trying to reproduce [this](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/samples/highcharts/annotations/mock-point/) highcharts using annotations in react with typescript. As you can see in a live [demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/m596v2v3v8) the annotations are not being displayed, and I assume it is due to some loading issues.

```
import * as React from "react";
import * as Highcharts from "highcharts";
import * as Annotations from "highcharts/modules/annotations";
```

Comment: any error in the console ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like DefinitelyTyped doesn't know about the `highcharts/modules/annotations` module.  So first, create a separate file `declarations.d.ts` with:

```
declare module "highcharts/modules/annotations";
```

In demo.tsx:

```
import * as Highcharts from "highcharts";
import AnnotationsFactory = require("highcharts/modules/annotations");
AnnotationsFactory(Highcharts);
```

And add `as any` after the big configuration object being passed to `Highcharts.chart` so that TypeScript doesn't complain about the `annotations` property.  (What you're doing seems to be valid at runtime but not recognized by the out-of-date typings.)

Finally, in `tsconfig.json`, change the `module` option from `esnext` to `commonjs` to be able to use the import assignment.

[Final CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/zl0ryykj5l).

Locally, I ran into some dependency issues and had to disable the tslint quotemark rule because it was blocking the build, but I ultimately got the annotations to work.  Let me know if you need help with that part.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Locally I now get the following error: `ReferenceError: AnnotationsFactory is not defined` Any idea?

Comment: Make sure you changed the `module` option to `commonjs`, otherwise TypeScript will ignore the erroneous import assignment.  If that wasn't it, please run `npm run start`, open `bundle.js` in your browser's development console, search the file for `AnnotationsFactory`, and add the relevant part of the file to the question so I can see what Webpack did.

Answer (score 4):

here is the official [link](https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-react#how-to-add-a-module) on how to use highchart modules

In this code example shown how to import highchart components

```
import Highcharts from 'highcharts'
import AnnotationsFactory from "highcharts/modules/annotations";
import HighchartsReact from 'highcharts-react-official'

// init the module
AnnotationsFactory(Highcharts);
```

After import you should use **HighchartsReact** component and add your annotation config there.

In this way it is possible to use any module for it.